# Silverlight Gradient Picker

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I need to implement a gradient picker. I really like Blend's one. Could I use it in my Silverlight app and how I can do this?
If not, is there some implementation of this control?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a built-in gradient picker control but you might find the [SilverDraw Library](http://www.markbetz.net/2009/09/02/color-tools-for-silverlight-2-2/) interesting (assemblies and source code available).

Answer (score 0):

I found [Silverlight ColorPicker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/Silverlight_ColorPicker.aspx), this may suite what you need.